# SaaS infrastructure for Java/Grails app

Tags: java, grails, heroku, cloud, cloud-foundry

I need to make a Grails app SAAS infrasctureture. I want "total data separation" (so multi-tenancy is not an option) and where user signs up I launch a new Heroku app. A good is http://www.getharvest.com/

I've a launch page which is at mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. I also have CNAME entry *.mydomain.com pointing to proxy.heroku.com (Heroku Mesh). I understand that following things should be done when a new user signs-up for the SAAS:

1) select app name: app-name.mydomain.com

2) username/password/role (optional) and pricing option

3) Then deploy code to a new Heroku instance (get from a git repo)

4) Add Heroku domain:add .mydomain.com

5) Use Heroku config:add to add the choices from step #2

Everything looks fine. But the problem is, can we automate the process? 
I'm looking for a way to do this (maybe a groovy script)

NOTE: heroku is not a requisite (could be another cloud service)

Cheers,

Raúl

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible with a Cloud Foundry based provider, it's open source along with the client library for automating deployment.

The java client is here - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client, I am not a Java / Groovy developer but I have pretty much got this working using Ruby by deconstructing the VMC (the CF Ruby client) source and using that to deploy sites.